# View is passed a list then how do I update on the post?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my GET I have:

```
return View(listOfEntries);
```

But then when I try to update in my Post the Entry object is all 0's.

Basically my view contains all entries for that particular id.  It is displaying fine but ultimately I want to be able to edit any of the existing Entry fields or add a new one.

Right now when I go into my POST

> public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include =
>   "EntryId,UserId,EntryQuestionId,EntryQuestion,EntryQuestionVotes,EntryAnswer,EntryReviews,
>   QuestionValidationURL,TopicId")] Entry entry)

The entry object has no values or 0's.  I'm guessing it is because the model was a list of entry objects but I'm not sure how I can accomplish what I'm trying to do.

My View:

```
@model List<projInterview.Models.Entry>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    var iLoopCount = 0;
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Entry</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.EntryId)
            <div class="form-group">
                @if(iLoopCount == 0)
                {
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => item.EntryQuestion, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.EntryQuestion)
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <hr/>
                }
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => item.EntryAnswer, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.EntryAnswer)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => item.EntryReviews, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @{
                var iCount = 0;
                var inputName = "EntryReviews" + item.EntryId;
                for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                {
                    iCount = i;
                    if (item.EntryReviews == i)
                    {
                        <input name=@inputName type="radio" class="star" checked="checked" value="@i" />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input name=@inputName type="radio" class="star" value="@i" />
                    }
                }
}
                </div>
                @*@Html.Partial("_ReviewPartial")*@
            </div>

            iLoopCount++;
            @*if (iLoopCount >= Model.Count())
            {
              <hr/>
              <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => item.EntryAnswer,"Add New Answer: ", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextArea("EntryAnswer",String.Empty)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.EntryAnswer)
                </div>
              </div>      
            }*@
        }




        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}


<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

My Controller (partial):

```
   // GET: /Entry/Edit/5
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Entry entry = db.Entries.Find(id);
    List<Entry> listOfEntries = new List<Entry>();
    listOfEntries = db.Entries.Where(e => e.EntryQuestionId == id).ToList();
    if (listOfEntries == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewBag.TopicId = new SelectList(db.Topics, "TopicId", "TopicName", entry.TopicId);
    return View(listOfEntries);
}

// POST: /Entry/Edit/5
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "EntryId,UserId,EntryQuestionId,EntryQuestion,EntryQuestionVotes,EntryAnswer,EntryReviews,QuestionValidationURL,TopicId")] Entry entry)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        EntryAnswerReview myReview = new EntryAnswerReview();
        myReview.EntryId = entry.EntryId;
        myReview.EntryAnswerReviewValue = entry.EntryReviews;
        myReview.DateReviewed = DateTime.Now;
        myReview.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        db.Reviews.Add(myReview);

        List<Int32> reviews = new List<Int32>();
        reviews = db.Reviews.Where(x => x.EntryId == entry.EntryId).Select(x => x.EntryAnswerReviewValue).ToList();
        Double average;
        if (reviews.Count == 0)
        {
            average = entry.EntryReviews;
        }
        else
        {
            average = reviews.Average();
        }


        entry.EntryReviews = Convert.ToInt32(average);

        entry.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        if (entry.UserId == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("User [" +
                User.Identity.Name + " ] not found.");
        }
        entry.LastUpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
        db.Entry(entry).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.TopicId = new SelectList(db.Topics, "TopicId", "TopicName", entry.TopicId);
    return View(entry);
}
```

**Further Clarification of what I want to do:**

Lets say the Edit View on the get returns 2 Entry items:

- Entry #1
- Entry #2

I want to be able to update either one of those from this view.

But I also want to have a "New Entry" option (Right now just a text area for the answer.  So in my controller if that is filled out I would like to be able to capture that a new entry is present and add it to the Database.

Comment: How are you editing the entries? Do you dynamically generate input tags?

Comment: It's not quite clear for me, do you expect one `Entry` object or the whole list?

Comment: want it all :) - I'm displaying all of the entries in the view with the ability (I'm hoping) to update and add a new entry all in that view.  Does that help?

Comment: [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) is Phil Haack's article about how the `DefaultModelBinder` with collections works, this will help you.

Comment: @Zabavsky Your link provided me the answer.  If you would like to post your link as the answer I will mark it as such.  I will also answer this question with some of the code and tid-bits that I learned along the way.